# Is "bit of oil" countable or uncountable?

Tags: idioms, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

If it is countable why do we say

> ***a*** little bit of oil

and can  I say the following?

> a little quantity of seeds

Comment: A fistfull of dollars is hardly worth thinking about.  A fistfull of hundred dollar bills is more worth your attention, however.

Comment: A little bit of oil would be about half a drop, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oil isn't countable when referring to a single type of oil, but it is countable when referring to different **types** of oil:  if I rub two different kinds of oil into my skin, then I could say I have rubbed *two different oils* into my skin.  Consider phrases like "Essential oils" for example.

Even with a single type of oil, the phrase *"bits of oil"* could be countable.  It's countable if it has a plural - *"You have some bits of oil on your shirt"*.

If one of those *"bits of oil"* was small, then you could say *"You have a little bit of oil on your shirt".*

It's worth noting that *"You have some bits of oil on your shirt"* could be replaced with *"You have a bit of oil on your shirt"*, even if there was more than one patch of oil.  *"A bit"* here means *"some"*.

You can say *"A little quantity of seeds"*, though I think "A small quantity" or *"a small amount"* would be more idiomatic.  (Quantity in this sense is synonymous with *"amount"*.)

Answer (score 1):

The expression

> [a little bit](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/a%20little%20bit)

is a fixed phrase or if you prefer, an idiom, and can be used with any noun, countable or uncountable. It is the word ***bit*** which is countable

SINGULAR

> - Here's **a** little bit of advice… (*advice* is normally uncountable)
> - There's **a** little bit of apple left. (*apple* is normally countable)

PLURAL

> - Here **are some** bits of advice
> - There **are some** bits of apple on the plate

Therefore, *a little bit of oil* is grammatically sound, and breaks no rules.

To talk about a restricted quantity of a substance we might say

> **a** small amount **of sugar**.
>   **a** small quantity **of rice**.

If we can literally count the thing being nominated then IMO "number" is preferable

> **a**  small number of **eggs**…